# Powershell Regex date conversion

Tags: regex, validation, date, powershell

any idea why the following isnt working?

.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
$files = @'
name 14122012 text.doc
things 08092003.docx
hi v03.03 text 05062007 file.txt
hello world 31052006.ppt
names v04 12122012.xml
sdsf 29082013 dsf.php

'@ -split '\n'
foreach ($File in $files) {

$file -match '(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(19|20)[0-9]{2}' | Out-Null
$File -replace "$(($matches).values)" , "$(get-date "$(($matches).Values)" -Format yyyyddMM)"
}
```

powershell output error is, for some reason its trying to add "20 12 14" to the string for conversion :S

```
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "20 12 14 14122012" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:13 char:9
+ get-date <<<< "$(($matches).Values)" -Format yyyyddMM
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :     CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

and

```
$files = @'
11.12.2012
11.12.12
15 12 2013
5 06 2013

'@ -split '\n'

foreach ($File in $files) {
$file -match '\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2,4}' | Out-Null
$file -match '(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s\d{2}\s\d{2,4}'| Out-Null

$File -replace "$(($matches).values)" , "$(get-date "$(($matches).Values)" -Format  yyyyMMdd)"

}

15 12 2013
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "15 15 12 2013" to      type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:13 char:9
+ get-date <<<<  "$(($matches).Values)" -Format yyyyMMdd
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :     CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand

5 06 2013
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "15 15 12 2013" to     type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:13 char:9
+ get-date <<<<  "$(($matches).Values)" -Format yyyyMMdd
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :    CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing what it's supposed to do.  $matches is a hash table of the the base capture (0) and each capture group:

```
$text = 'name 14122012 text.doc'
$regex = $file -match '(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(19|20)[0-9]{2}' | Out-Null

$matches

Name                           Value                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                 
3                              2013                                                                  
2                              08                                                                    
1                              29                                                                    
0                              29082013
```

When you ouput the collection of values as a string, it's going to space separate them:

```
"$(($matches).values)"

2013 08 29 29082013
```

That's the normal behaviour for any collection that's converted to a string. You can change the separator character from the default space by changing the Output Field Separator ($OFS)

```
$OFS = ';'
"$(($matches).values)"

2013;08;29;29082013
```

That being said, you really don't need to jump through the datetime conversion hoops.  You have all the data you need already:

```
$files = @'
name 14122012 text.doc
things 08092003.docx
hi v03.03 text 05062007 file.txt
hello world 31052006.ppt
names v04 12122012.xml
sdsf 29082013 dsf.php

'@ -split '\n'
foreach ($File in $files) {

$file -match '(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])((?:19|20)[0-9]{2})' | Out-Null
$File -replace "$($matches[0])" , ($matches[3,2,1] -join '')
}


name 20121214 text.doc
things 20030908.docx
hi v03.03 text 20070605 file.txt
hello world 20060531.ppt
names v04 20121212.xml
sdsf 20130829 dsf.php
```

It just took a minor re-factoring of the regex to capture all of the year digits, then arrange the captures in the right order and join them together.

Comment: Awesome, thanks works great though how do I deal with spaces for both combinations?>> e.g 26 12 2012 and 2013 09 30 to>> 20121226 and 20130930

Comment: That's what the -join is doing.  You can also eliminate the spaces by setting $OFS to '', but you need to be careful with changing preference values in the global scope.

Comment: Doesnt seem to want to work for me, Should it not be included in the Regex e.g (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/s(0[1-9]|1[012])/s((?:19|20)[0-9]{2}) to indicate to find spaces? (though that doesnt work for me either)

Comment: The regex for a space is \s, not /s.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you weren't capturing the entire year (only the first 2 digits), so you need to move the group capture bracket:

```
$file -match '(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(19|20[0-9]{2})'
```

Also, `$matches` returns an array that contains the entire matched string in the first element, followed by an element for each captured group.

For example:

```
"name 14122012 text.doc" -match '(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(19|20[0-9]{2})'
$matches

Name                           Value                                              
----                           -----                                              
3                              2012                                               
2                              12                                                 
1                              14                                                 
0                              14122012
```

So you have to recombine the string in a format the get-date will like. In my locale, it would look like this:

```
$matches[2,1,3] -join " "
12 14 2012
```

If your locale needs the day of month first, then:

```
$matches[1..3] -join " "
14 12 2012
```

which then gives:

```
$File -replace "$($matches[0])" , "$(get-date $($matches[2,1,3] -join ' ') -Format yyyyddMM)"
```

for your second line.